# rmi server listening on 2 different ips

Tags: java, docker, rmi

I'm relatively new to Java.
Currently I am working on an application that has a server written in rmi.

It listens at 127.0.0.1 port 2020 for clients sending remote logs.
My new client is under a docker container and requires me to go though another IP that is the gateway of the container. Now I have to listen at this IP 169.X.X.X:2020 as well (cannot alter any code of existing clients)

```
RMIClientSocketFactory csf = NAClientSocketFactory.getInstance();
RMIServerSocketFactory ssf = NAServerSocketFactory.getInstance();
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( REGISTRY_PORT, csf, ssf);

logger = new RemoteAuditLoggerImpl ();
stub = (IRemoteAuditLogger) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(logger, REGISTRY_PORT, csf, 
ssf);
registry.bind (REMOTE_AUDIT_LOGGER_RMI_NAME, stub);
```

Now, if I want to listen at 169.X.X.X , create registry does not let me choose the IP. I can only do it using the ssf RMIServerSocketFactory. Suppose I change the IP there, 127.0.0.1:2020 will not be opened.
Trying to do a duplicate of

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( REGISTRY_PORT, csf, ssf);
```

will throw: java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use

Is this even possible to register using 2 IPs?

Comment: Why will rmi server has to  listen to your another IP address?

Comment: It doesn't make sense of processing running on your machine , lisenting to my ip address.

Above code is server code which create rmi registry - it acts as server. clients can get that registy and call remote method invocation

Comment: The client that runs under docker, cannot reach 127.0.0.1. I tried stuff and the only solution that worked is changing the rmi IP in both client and server to 169.X.X.X. otherwise I get connection refused.

Comment: are you Running both client and server on same machine?

Comment: Your Ip address 196.* is public ip address. since your docker image is able to connect to internet it's able to access RMI

Comment: to need to enable network while running docker.
Use --network="host" in your docker run command, then 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host.

Comment: yes, I'm running both clients and server on the same machine.
Also I've tried to configure the client to the host public IP, before considering changes in the server. The response was "connection refused".

Comment: By default any remote object will listen at all IP addresses, i.e. INADDR_ANY. Just *remove* any specific IP address usage from your `ServerSocketFactory` and let this happen. Job done.

Comment: I changed the server socket factory to return new ServerSocket(port); then tried to telnet the machineIP 2020 - still connection refused (127.0.0.1 works)

Comment: Connection refused to what IP doesn't work?

Comment: 169.X.X.X and host external IP

Comment: Something wrong there. 169.xx.xx.xx is a local-only subnet that isn't supposed to get routed. A network node should not have such an address. The public IP needs port forwarding.